# Manipulating sortname field in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I provide certain bibliography entries with the option `frg` to achieve a bit of a different format than for the rest of my entries. Among other things, I want to have them sorted by editor instead of by author. My idea was to automatically copy the `editor` field to the `sortname` field to achieve this, so I used the following code in my `bbx`-file:

```
\newbool{cbx:frg}
\DeclareEntryOption{frg}[true]{\csuse{bool#1}{cbx:frg}}%
\AtDataInput{%
  \ifbool{cbx:frg}{%
     \savename*{editor}{\bbx@blah}%
     \restorename{sortname}{\bbx@blah}%
   }{}%
}%
```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ignore the `author` field for sorting (and use `editor` resp. `title` instead), simply add `options = {useauthor=false},` to the respective bibliography entries. See section 3.3.3.1 of the biblatex manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  options = {useauthor=false},
  author = {Author, A.},
  editor = {Zuthor, Z.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  editor = {Yuthor, Y.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  editor = {Xuthor, X.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to make my option `frg` imply the option `useauthor=false`? I'm trying to avoid having to alter the bib file.... Thanks!

Comment: @Jonathan: I don't know how to do this. Sounds like a new question.